# android: How to get the current ValueEventListener attached to a Query?

Tags: android, firebase

I am using ValueEventListeners to retrieve data from Firebase database. and now I would like to remove a ValueEventListener from a Query. Something like this:

```
query.removeEventListener(listener);
```

In case of getting Exceptions, I want to check if the listener was already added to the query before I actually remove it. However, I just couldn't find out how to check if the query "has" listeners; nor could I get the current listener that is attached to the query. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. You need to use the following code:

```
if(listener != null) {
    query.removeEventListener(listener);
}
```

If your listener is not equal to null, means that was already attached and you need to remove it, otherwise you don't meed to do anything.

Note, that you need to remove the listener according to the life-cycle of your activity.

According to [Query class offical documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query), there is no method for getting the listener of a query. Once you have added the listener, you only have to remove it. You cannot check the state of a listener that was passed as an argument.

Comment: You are wrong. You can have a listener created(not null) but not attached. The question was: Is there a way to know if the Query have listeners attached?

Comment: @RazvanCristianLung In my understanding, if someone is using `query.removeEventListener(listener);` means that the listener was first created and then attached. So, if the listener was attached to that particular query it is mandatory to be removed. The only way to verify this it's to check for nullity.

Comment: Agree, the user have to manually set the listener to null as the docs tells us. But still, the OP question is different.

Comment: Thank you @Razvan Cristian Lung! Cheers!

Comment: Keep in mind that the `removeEventListener(listener);` method runs asynchronously, which may create some bug you were not expecting... Especially if your callback creates other listeners, which are supposed to be attached only once. I've just spent more than 3 hours on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a list of the listeners that you added so you need to keep track of them, but you can safely call query.removeEventListener(listener). If the given listener is not attached nothing will happen.

Keep in mind thought, that you need to manually remove all the listeners attached to the DatabaseReference, or else they will the triggered.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way that is recommended in the Firebase blog somewhere. I've somewhat modified it over time, however it does allow you to get the state of your active listeners as the op requested. See code comments for other features.

Create your database reference and ValueEventListener as you normally do.
Use this class to attach and detach them for you. I've added a `getListenerState()` method.

Instantiate this class as your listener and pass in either `(DatabasReference, ValueEventListener)` or `(Query, ValueEventListener)` whichever your are using.

Then you can call:
`changeListenerState(boolean activeState)` to change the listeners state.
`getListenerState()` to get the listeners state for any listeners that you have attached this class to.

```
/**
 * Used to attach and detach listeners to DatabaseReferences and Queries. Adds a 2 second
 * delay when a listener is removed to prevent unnecessary re-querying due to configuration changes
 * etc.
 */
public class DataListenerPending {

private static final String TAG = "DataListenerPending";

private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private final Query mQuery;
private final ValueEventListener mListener;
private boolean mListenerRemovePending = false;
private boolean mListenerState = false;

private final Runnable mRemoveListener = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mQuery.removeEventListener(mListener);
        mListenerRemovePending = false;
        mListenerState = false;
    }
};

/**
 * @param query A reference to the query object from which the data is derived. It is used
 *              by this class to attach and detach the listener.
 * @param listener the listener to attach to this query.
 */
public DataListenerPending(Query query, ValueEventListener listener) {
    this.mQuery = query;
    this.mListener = listener;
}

/**
 * @param reference A reference to the query object from which the data is derived.
 *                          It is used by this class to attach and detach the listener.
 * @param listener The listener to attach to this reference.
 */
public DataListenerPending(DatabaseReference reference, ValueEventListener listener) {
    this.mQuery = reference;
    this.mListener = listener;
}

/**
 * Adds and removes the listener when called
 * @param attachState true to add a listener, false to remove it.
 */
public void changeListenerState(boolean attachState) {
    if (attachState) {
        if (mListenerRemovePending) {
            // If asked to attach listener and it is currently in a state of pending removal,
            // stop it from being removed.
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRemoveListener);
        } else {
            // Only attach listener if it is not already attached.
            if (!mListenerState) {
                mQuery.addValueEventListener(mListener);
                mListenerState = true;
            }
        }
        mListenerRemovePending = false;
    } else {
        // Request to remove listener received. Wait for 2 secs to account for config changes.
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRemoveListener, 2000);
        mListenerRemovePending = true;
    }
}

public boolean getListenerState() {
    return mListenerState;
}
```

}